# Canvas Pod During Button and Redirecting via Segue

Tags: ios, canvas, swift3, cocoapods

I recently found the Canvas framework to make animations. I have a button that on click, the animation plays. So I tried connecting a segue to preform the animation THEN go to the second view controller but in the simulator the app just goes to the other view controller, it doesn't show the animation. I'm pretty sure I've installed Canvas correctly.

Comment: What does the console show when your app crashes? or any log?

Comment: sorry i made an edit